# Android Runtime Exception when starting an intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to launch an activity when my application starts, but it immediately crashes with a runtime exception. Strangely, an identical activity will work just fine, with the only difference being the name of the activity.

Here is what I'm calling:

```
int SignupActivityId = 0;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignupActivity.class); // Crashes
//Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewGameActivity.class); // Doesn't not crash
this.startActivityForResult(intent, SignupActivityId);
```

Here is the definition for each activity, notice they are practically identical, even to loading the same resource xml:

SignupActivity - Crashes

```
package com.example.games.MyGame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SignupActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_game);
    }
}
```

NewGameActivity - does not crash

```
package com.example.games.MyGame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewGameActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_game);
    }
}
```

How can SignupActivity crash, but NewGameActivity doesn't??

Comment: What is the exception and is the activity defined in the manifest?

Comment: Could you post the exact error-message? And where do you fire your Intent?

Comment: My guess would be that the Manifest declares one of the activities (the one that doest crash) but the other one is undeclared.

Comment: Is that all both Activities do ? Or did you trim out any code before posting ? If there is more code, then does the crashing activity do anything that your manifest doesnt have a permission for ?

Comment: @Ryan Olds. I think you may have cracked it. The other activities are definitely defined in the manifest, but as it was late last I forgot to add the new "SignupActivity" to the manifest. I shall check it out when I get home, but I imagine that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, after checking LogCat, the layout xml was missing an android:layout_width from one of the views. It turns out that's required.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have defined the Activity "SignupActivity" into your AndroidManifest.xml??? =D
use the LogCat to get the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. You have int SignupActivityId = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `startActivity(intent);` ?